# Using R for Text Mining Reuters-21578

Tags: r, corpus, tm, reuters

I am trying to do some work with the well known Reuters-21578 dataset and am having some trouble with loading the sgm files into my corpus.

Right now I am using the command

```
require(tm)
reut21578 <- system.file("reuters21578", package = "tm")
reuters <-Corpus(DirSource(reut21578), 
    readerControl = list(reader = readReut21578XML))
```

In an attempt to include all the files into my corpus but this gives me the following error:

```
Error in DirSource(reut21578) : empty directory
```

Any idea where I may be going wrong?

Comment: Have a look at this question - it looks like that data is not included with the `tm` package and you may have to manually download before proceeding. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377273/tm-package-error-error-definining-document-term-matrix

Comment: @Stedy: The link you provided will definitely be helpful for the rest of my analysis but I have already downloaded the data and what I am doing just doesn't seem to be finding the proper directory.

Comment: ahh gotcha, ok what I think is happening is that R is looking in the source code directory for `tm`. Why not simplify things by putting the file in `Documents` or Desktop and just call it as `file("Documents/reuters-21578")`

Comment: @Stedy is correct, @user1422508 you should replace `Corpus(DirSource(reut21578)...` with `Corpus(DirSource("full-path-to-dir-with-downloaded-data")...`

Answer (score 6):

The "tm" package includes only sample of the Reuters21578 data. If you want to avoid downloading, loading and preparing all the 22 Reuters21578 files, you can use package "tm.corpus.Reuters21578":

```
install.packages("tm.corpus.Reuters21578", repos = "http://datacube.wu.ac.at")
library(tm.corpus.Reuters21578)
data(Reuters21578)
```

Comment: There is a comment claiming that the URL doesn't work any more. That is the thing with links, they tend to break. Thus "link only" answers are discouraged ...

Comment: It gives me some warnings, but then the package downloads just fine. I also don't think that this is true example of "link only" answer.

Comment: If you could please tell us why we're getting the "Empty Directory" as well, that'd be great, because I converted all SGM files to XML myself, and it's a shame to not get them working.

Comment: I tried your answer but I get `RROR: dependency ‘XML’ is not available for package ‘tm.corpus.Reuters21578’` even though I have install `libxml2-dev`