# text mining with r remove words?

Tags: r, text-mining

I do set stop words and  believe this should work while what happened is:

```
library(tm)
myStopwords <- c(stopwords('english'), "rt", "and")
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removeWords, myStopwords)

Error in UseMethod("tm_map", x) : 
  no applicable method for 'tm_map' applied to an object of class "character"
```

Does anyone have any idea with that?
Thanks!

Comment: See comments under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45514472/no-applicable-method-for-tm-map-applied-to-an-object-of-class-character). `tm_map` is applied to a corpus object, not a character vector. Perhaps you need to apply `removeWords` to the text before conversion to a corpus - what type of object is `myCorpus` ?